# 1:M relation exclude row if any row in M table does not contain specific value

Tags: mysql

Consider I have following table `products`

```
group   ads status
X       ad1 ACTIVE
X       ad2 NOT_BUYABLE
X       ad3 PAUSED
Y       ad4 ACTIVE
Y       ad5 SUSPENDED
Y       ad6 PAUSED
Z       ad7 ACTIVE
Z       ad8 OUT_OF_BUDGET
Z       ad9 ARCHIVED
```

All I want is to filter distinct group

For example, I want to filter the group where

1. the product status != NOT_BUYABLE
2. AND the product status = ACTIVE

consider Group X:

- ad1 = ACTIVE
- ad2 = NOT_BUYABLE
- ad3 = PAUSED

**This filter would ignore Group X**

consider Group Y:

- ad4 = ACTIVE
- ad5 = SUSPENDED
- ad6 = PAUSED

**This filter would return Group Y**

consider Group Z:

- ad7 = ACTIVE
- ad8 = OUT_OF_BUDGET
- ad9 = ARCHIVED

**This filter would return Group Z**

so final output should be

```
group
Y
Z
```

This means the user only wants to filter product that doesn't have any NOT_BUYABLE status values but has at least 1 ACTIVE status.

when I apply != operator I have to make sure none of the product under that group has those staus

This SQL query is wrong

```
Select  distinct `group`   from products
where status != 'NOT_BUYABLE' and status = 'ACTIVE';
```

Let me know what will be the SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Plan D** can be

```
SELECT
`group`
    , SUM(CASE 
            WHEN STATUS = 'NOT_BUYABLE'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) NOT_BUYABLE
    , SUM(CASE 
            WHEN STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) ACTIVE
FROM testproductads
GROUP BY
`group`
HAVING NOT_BUYABLE = 0
    AND ACTIVE > 0;
```

Comment: A shorter way to SUM:  `SUM(status = 'ACTIVE')` .  This works because a boolean expression is treated as 0 for false and 1 for true.

Answer (score 3):

Plan A:

```
SELECT a.group
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT `group` FROM tbl ) AS a
    WHERE
         EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE group = a.group
                                      AND status = 'ACTIVE' )
     AND
     NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE group = a.group
                                      AND status = 'NOT_BUYABLE' )
```

Plan B:

```
SELECT a.group,
       GROUP_CONCAT(status) AS stati
    FROM tbl AS a
    GROUP BY `group`
    HAVING      FIND_IN_SET('ACTIVE',      stati)
        AND NOT FIND_IN_SET('NOT_BUYABLE', stati)
```

(To get rid of the second column, you need to wrap that in another `SELECT`.)

(Suggest changing your column name away from the keyword "group".)

Recommend this for both queries:

```
 INDEX(`group`, `status`)
```

(I don't know which Plan will be faster.)

Comment: I have modified it like this
`Select   group
    ,count(*)- SUM(CASE WHEN status != 'NOT_BUYABLE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NOT_BUYABLE
    ,count(*)- SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ACTIVE
    from testproductads
    group by group
    having NOT_BUYABLE = 0 and ACTIVE > 0;`

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Rick James' plan B but using `MIN(<CASE expression>)` as aggregate instead of - the possibly more expensive - `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `FIND_IN_SET()`:

**Plan C** (C1/C2: with and without the `WHERE`)

```
SELECT a.group
    FROM tbl AS a
 -- WHERE a.status IN ('ACTIVE', 'NOT_BUYABLE')
    GROUP BY a.group
    HAVING  MIN(CASE WHEN a.status = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) = 'ACTIVE'
        AND MIN(CASE WHEN a.status = 'NOT_BUYABLE' THEN 1 END) IS NULL ;
```

Comment: Or maybe something using `ANY()`?

Comment: @RickJames yeah, I suppose it could be wrten with `ANY` as well. To be honest, I'd use the `EXISTS` approach in your answer or similar. I've seen various cases of this type of queries and - in many real life distributions of data - the `EXISTS` method beats the `GROUP BY` by far...

Comment: Of course, when you data is a few thousands or million rows, the various methods make very small difference.

Answer (score 1):

Variation from other answers in thread, plan E seems to be the case:

```
SELECT grp
FROM testproductads
GROUP BY grp
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS <> 'NOT_BUYABLE' THEN 1 END) = COUNT(1)     
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) >= 1
```

[Mubbashar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/86989/mubbashar) variant for buyable is more efficient since it does not have to COUNT(1)

```
SELECT grp
FROM testproductads
GROUP BY grp
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'NOT_BUYABLE' THEN 1 END) = 0     
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) >= 1
```